# Where can I find the POW hash of blocks?

Tags: blockchain, block-explorer, proof-of-work, programming-languages

I want to find the POW hashes of each block, which start with or end with many zeros.

[This answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5846/5951) showed an example of the POW hash.

I tried many blockchain explorers and didn't find any one with POW hashes.

Is there an easy way to find the POW hashes, like a blockchain explorer or some python script?

Comment: I don't know if there's a simple script to do this. You might need to build monero and use some of the built library functions to get this data. Are you looking for python specifically? I've started a project to bind python to Monero's build but I haven't mapped any of the blockchain utility modules yet. https://github.com/ehanoc/pymonero . If you understand python and a bit of c++ you can map these functions.

Comment: This is the code that calculates the POW hash: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/c102c49da5015592d2a2fedf0ae348495ec382df/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L1015

Answer (score 1):

To find the PoW hash of a block, you perform two steps:

- get the hashing blob for that block (`get_block_hashing_blob` in the Monero source), which is built by serializing the block, and appending the number of transactions in that block as well as the root of the Merkle tree
- run Cryptonight (`cn_slow_hash` in the Monero source) on this blob

If you just want to lookup the PoW hash of a particular block, you can use the `print_block` command in monerod, giving either a height or a block hash, eg:

`print_block 87493`

Comment: There is no POW hash in the output of `print_block` command

Comment: Hmm. That is true. I thought there was. Please file a bug on github.com/monero-project/monero asking for it then.

Comment: I've made such a patch: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3561